# What are __bad_copy_from and __bad_copy_to?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to find the source code for `__bad_copy_from` and `__bad_copy_to`, but I can't seem to find it.

How can I analyze this code? From `thread_info.h`:

```c
extern void __compiletime_error("copy source size is too small")
__bad_copy_from(void);
extern void __compiletime_error("copy destination size is too small")
__bad_copy_to(void);
```

Answer (score 1):

Those two functions don't have an implementation. They are merely *declared* with the macro `__compiletime_error(message)`, which expands to `__attribute__((error(message)))` as defined in [`include/linux/compiler-gcc.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h#L194):

```c
#ifndef __CHECKER__
# define __compiletime_warning(message) __attribute__((warning(message)))
# define __compiletime_error(message) __attribute__((error(message)))
#endif /* __CHECKER__ */
```

They will result in a compile-time error if the compiler is not able to optimize away their call.

The `error` function attribute is [documented by GCC here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> If the `error` or `warning` attribute is used on a function declaration and a call to such a function is not eliminated through dead code elimination or other optimizations, an error or warning (respectively) that includes message is diagnosed.
>
> [...]
>
> While it is possible to leave the function undefined and thus invoke a link failure (to define the function with a message in .gnu.warning* section), when using these attributes the problem is diagnosed earlier and with exact location of the call even in presence of inline functions or when not emitting debugging information.

So those two functions, which have no implementation, are used as safety checks in parts of the code that are only reached if bad sizes are used to perform a copy operation (e.g. `copy_{to,from}_user`), and thus should never actually be reachable.